# A javascript file is missing from the openui5 CDN

Tags: sapui5

The CDN for openui5 appears to be missing this js file:

../resources/sap/m/dialog.js

Frustratingly i use the CDN to serve the OPENUI5 files (and I DO NOT want my own copy on my server)
When serving up locally from a local install of the SDK this works fine!

This has not been deprecated.

[image: missing openui5 file?!]

Comment: appears to be an access control (CORS) issue which makes no sense given the nature of a CDN - not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your server is on Windows system, which is not case-sensitive OS, but CDN is served by *nix system which is case-sensitive, so you have to use the correct name of a control starting with capital letter. Try "**sap.m.Dialog**" as it's described in documentation.